# Disable zoom when user press input

Tags: android, webview

Tell me how to Disable zoom when pressing input in webview? Insert here the following line in oncreate, but it still increases when entering the password

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
// it is my code
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(180);
```

Comment: Could you explain your question in better detail? It does not make much sense

Comment: Look, I have a field on the page login and password, everything look normal, and works well, but there is a problem - when a user clicks a field for entering a password or login, the browser window increases, and the site is not recognized correctly, can we do so that would be when the user clicks the login fields, not approaching webviev page?